# How Entity Framework can save parent and dependent child record using Create Action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have following Model diagram, in which Address entity depends on Profile entity. 
[image]

I have created a Create view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
<h4>Profile</h4>            
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<br />
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Address.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
}
```

And this is the action that EF has scaffolded for me:

```
public ActionResult Create(Profile profile)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Profiles.Add(profile);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(profile);
    }
```

How can I achieve what I want to achieve what I want to.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should create relevant records in Profile and Address tables. What is the problem?

Comment: After checking again and again, now it looks working. Before this it was creating some kind of error, I don't remember the error message. Thanks